# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 vfs TransportSender as Endpoint Errors with 'Access is denied'

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to put together a proof of concept for the use of wso2 esb. The proof of concept will rely on the ESB picking up a csv file dropped into a folder, converting the details to xml, posting them to a 3rd party web service, then converting the response, which should contain the binary for a pdf, into a pdf and dropping it into a folder.

The current problem with this is that when I configure a folder as an endpoint in wso2 esb 4.5.0, any file that I send to that end-point errors. A stripped down version of my configuration is as defined below: -

```
<proxy name="PDFPoller"
      transports="vfs"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="enable"
      statistics="enable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="status" value="PDF Receieved"/>
        </log>
        <log level="full"/>
        <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                  expression="test1.pdf"
                  scope="transport"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        <send>
           <endpoint name="FileEpr">
              <address uri="vfs:file:///c:/wso2/processed"/>
           </endpoint>
        </send>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///C:/wso2/output</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///C:/wso2/PollFolder</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///C:/wso2/Failed</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.pdf</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/pdf</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
```

The error that I get from the ESB is as follows: -

```
2012-10-29 09:46:00,642 [-] [Axis2 Task] ERROR VFSTransportSender IO Error while 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not write to "file:///c:/wso2/processed".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getOutputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1440)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.DefaultFileContent.getOutputStream(DefaultFileContent.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender.populateResponseFile(VFSTransportSender.java:232)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender.sendMessage(VFSTransportSender.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:627)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\wso2\processed (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.local.LocalFile.doGetOutputStream(LocalFile.java:220)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getOutputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1432)
    ... 8 more
```

I don't believe that the problem is a local folder permissions problem, because I have a) checked the permissions on the folder manually and b) The ESB will move the file that I place in the 'pollfolder' to either 'Output' or 'Processed' if I set the transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess property to that value, so it is possible to write to both these folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configuration seems fine. But I suspect the following section.

```
<property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                  expression="test1.pdf"
                  scope="transport"/>
```

You can try without that property. Then it will create a file as same as the input file name inside the "processed" folder. If it works then try the above property as follows.

```
<property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                  value="test1.pdf"
                  scope="transport"/>
```

As you can see, I have replaced "expression" attribute with "value". Expression should be used when you want to execute something, for example concatenating two strings to build the response file name etc.

Comment: That works. Incidentally, expression also works as long as I use an expression, e.g <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat('test1', '.pdf')" scope="transport"/>. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. Expression works when you provide an expression there. But previously you had provided a value for an expression. That was the reason for the failure.